# UK Postcode -> Easting, Northing

Tags: gis

Is anyone aware of a free web service which allows me to translate uk postcodes to easting and northings. I found a website where I can use screen scraping but perhaps there is a nice FREE web service out there. Thanks!

Christian

Comment: This would be a good question for the new GIS StackExchange over at http://gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [NPE Map](http://www.npemap.org.uk/api/geocoder.shtml)

Comment: Thanks nice one. This works fine. I am using C# and used this: http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2006/04/21/76044.aspx

Comment: Seems to be really fast too and I presume they have the freshest data

Comment: @csetzkorn this is "crowdsourced" data created by volunteers entering postcodes against 50 year old 1:50 000 maps. It's not necessarily very accurate.

Comment: just to be controversial; you can still get the RoyalMail database of wikileaks.

Answer (score 7):

The ordnance survey have open sourced their list of postcodes including geographic coordinates (you may have to do some converting though). I haven't used the data myself yet, but I think [this](http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html) fits the bill.

> Code-Point Open is a dataset that contains postcode units, each of which have a precise geographical location.
>
> There are approximately 1.7 million postcode units in England, Scotland and Wales. Each postcode unit, such as KY12 8UP or PO14 2RS, contains an average of fifteen adjoining addresses.
>
> Northern Ireland postcodes are not available with Code-Point Open.

Note that due to the nature of the british postcode system, updates happen quite frequently during a year. Make sure you download new versions as they are released.

Comment: More info and links at http://www.freepostcodes.org.uk/

Answer (score 1):

The Codepoint postcode database was released in 2010 as open data as a zipped series of CSV files.

If you are converting a mass of postcodes, you'll find it more efficient to locate the databases on your own system as calling to an on-line API results in your scraper waiting longer than you would have expected for a response.

You can order the postcode data from the official site here:
    https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/oswebsite/products/code-point-open/index.html

Or simply download it from this copy:
    http://www.freepostcodes.org.uk/

The Northern Ireland data is not included, but there is a copy of the data here:
    http://jamiethompson.co.uk/web/2010/05/30/code-point-open-northern-ireland-addendum/

Save work.

The python code for parsing these two files is here:
    http://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/uk_postcodes_from_codepoint/edit/
    http://scraperwiki.com/scrapers/ni_postcodes_from_codepoint/edit/

The python CGI script code for looking up into these two databases is here:
    http://scraperwikiviews.com/run/uk_postcode_lookup/?

Answer (score 1):

If you are processing a lot of data then might be better to use your own local solution. Here is a Python script that can make the conversion:
http://webscraping.com/blog/Converting-UK-Easting-Northing-coordinates/

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

v84 = Proj(proj="latlong",towgs84="0,0,0",ellps="WGS84")
v36 = Proj(proj="latlong", k=0.9996012717, ellps="airy",
    towgs84="446.448,-125.157,542.060,0.1502,0.2470,0.8421,-20.4894")
vgrid = Proj(init="world:bng")


def ENtoLL84(easting, northing):
    """Returns (longitude, latitude) tuple
    """
    vlon36, vlat36 = vgrid(easting, northing, inverse=True)
    return transform(v36, v84, vlon36, vlat36)

def LL84toEN(longitude, latitude):
    """Returns (easting, northing) tuple
    """
    vlon36, vlat36 = transform(v84, v36, longitude, latitude)
    return vgrid(vlon36, vlat36)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # outputs (-1.839032626389436, 57.558101915938444)
    print ENtoLL84(409731, 852012)
```